# Unit Testing: Should I verify after testing section in a method?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, mockito

I have just started Unit Testing and I am a little bit confused regarding to the following issues. Could you help me please?

Here is the sample service method that I am testing:

```
public CommandDTO update(UUID uuid, Request request) {

    // case 1
    if (uuid == null) {
        throw new EntityNotFoundException("Not found");
    }

    final Employee employee = employeeService.findByUuid(uuid);
    
    // case 2
    if (employee.getDepartmentUuid == null) {
        throw new EntityNotFoundException("Not found");
    }

    employeeRepository.saveAndFlush(employee);

    triggerService.onEmployeeUpdate(uuid);

    return CommandDTO.builder().uuid(employee.getUuid()).build();
}
```

**1.** When I create a test method for testing case 1, should I just write a test for expecting `EntityNotFoundException`? I mean should I write verify lines after testing exception as shown below? Or should I just test until the part that I am testing? Because if I verify the rest, in that case I will repeat the same lines for all the other tests.

```
@Test
public void test_exception_when_update() {
    UUID uuid = null;
    Request request = new Request();

    assertThrows(EntityNotFoundException.class, () -> {
        employeeService.update(uuid, request);
    });

    /// ???
    verify(employeeService, never()).findByUuid(any());
    verify(employeeRepository, never()).saveAndFlush(any());
    verify(triggerService, never()).onEmployeeUpdate(any());
}
```

**2.** For the above service method, I think I should write the test methods for the following scenarios:

- `uuid == null` --> throw exception
- `employee.getDepartmentUuid` --> throw exception
- there is no exception and the other 3 operations are ok and then return `CommandDTO`. Then I will make assertions.

Is that true?

Comment: @AdriaanKoster Any help please?

Comment: Does any experienced developer has never write Unit Test for this kind of scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in both ways. But verifying won't do any harm.
Imagine the scenario:
your `update()` method is changed to save employee even if `uuid` is not given or found employee doesn't have `departmentUUID`. In that case, you can catch these new changes if you include your verify-checks, because the test will fail.

Comment: In this scenario, if I do not use verify, will it fail again? Or not?

Comment: If you don't verify test will not fail, it will pass. So you won't be able to tell the method has been changed.

Comment: But in the test method when there is no exception, I will verify and assert all the necessary lines. Then I am not sure if I also verify extra in the other test methods that are for exception. Any idea?